# MySQL convert time minutes_seconds into seconds

Tags: php, mysql, time

Hi fellow overflow users, I've been searching for how to convert a given time given as HHhMMmssS ex: `28m54s or 1h22m3s or 27s` into pure seconds with a MySQL command.

Output should be in pure seconds like:

```
from: 28m54s  -> 1734
from: 1h22m3s  ->  4923
from: 27s  ->  27
```

These values have been imported into a column called length.

If this can't be done, the second best choice would be PHP. This is to a one of job so a copy paste answer can do :)

MariaDB structure

```
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `embed` varchar(800) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `keywords` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `length` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `source_thumb_url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `record_num` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT

MariaDB [csv_import]> SHOW COLUMNS FROM table_name;
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field            | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| title            | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| embed            | varchar(800) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| description      | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| keywords         | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| length           | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| source_thumb_url | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| record_num       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Select string

```
SET @from = '`length`';
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(STR_TO_DATE(
    CONCAT(IF(@from LIKE '%h%', '', '0h'), IF(@from LIKE '%m%', '', '0m'), IF(@from LIKE '%s%', '', '0s'), @from),
    '%kh%im%ss')) AS sec;
```

Result of using UPDTAE

```
UPDATE `database_name`.`table_name` SET `length` = SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(STR_TO_DATE(
    CONCAT(IF(`length` LIKE '%h%', '', '0h'), IF(`length` LIKE '%m%', '', '0m'), `length`),
    '%kh%im%ss'));
```

returns: Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'select time_to_sec(str_to_date(
    CONCAT(IF(`length` like '%h%', '', '0h'), I' at line 1

And made the changes on table length

```
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| title            | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| embed            | varchar(800) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| description      | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| keywords         | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| length           | varchar(20)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| source_thumb_url | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| record_num       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

UPDATE to Strawberry's answer

```
SELECT CASE WHEN `length` LIKE '%h%' 
            THEN TIME_TO_SEC(STR_TO_DATE(`length`,'%hh%im%ss')) 
            WHEN `length` LIKE '%m%' 
            THEN TIME_TO_SEC(STR_TO_DATE(`length`,'%im%ss')) 
            ELSE TIME_TO_SEC(STR_TO_DATE(`length`,'%ss')) 
            END X;
```

Error Code: 1054
Unknown column 'length' in 'field list'

Comment: What data types do you use, which you want to convert from? This might help: [TIME_TO_SEC(time)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec)

Comment: Hi Paul Spiegel, just updated my question, as I noticed that lack of information :/ and thx for your link :) but the letters h m s challenge me

Comment: One thing that's confusing is that you say "these values have been imported into a column called length", but these values are clearly strings, and length is clearly an integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following query utilizing `time_to_sec` and `str_to_date`.

```
select time_to_sec(str_to_date(
    CONCAT(IF(@from like '%h%', '', '0h'), IF(@from like '%m%', '', '0m'), @from),
    '%kh%im%ss')) as sec;
```

### Demo:

```
mysql> set @from = '28m54s';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
mysql> select time_to_sec(str_to_date(
    ->     CONCAT(IF(@from like '%h%', '', '0h'), IF(@from like '%m%', '', '0m'), @from),
    ->     '%kh%im%ss')) as sec;
+------+
| sec  |
+------+
| 1734 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> set @from = '1h22m3s';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
mysql> select time_to_sec(str_to_date(
    ->     CONCAT(IF(@from like '%h%', '', '0h'), IF(@from like '%m%', '', '0m'), @from),
    ->     '%kh%im%ss')) as sec;
+------+
| sec  |
+------+
| 4923 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> set @from = '27s';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
mysql> select time_to_sec(str_to_date(
    ->     CONCAT(IF(@from like '%h%', '', '0h'), IF(@from like '%m%', '', '0m'), @from),
    ->     '%kh%im%ss')) as sec;
+------+
| sec  |
+------+
|   27 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Base on the table structure provided, you may need to change type for column `length` from `int(11)` to `varchar(20)`.

The new structure may be like this:

```
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `embed` varchar(800) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `keywords` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `length` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `source_thumb_url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `record_num` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Then after the import, use the following `update` to do  the desired conversion.

```
update table_name 
set `length` = time_to_sec(str_to_date(
    CONCAT(IF(`length` like '%h%', '', '0h'), IF(`length` like '%m%', '', '0m'), `length`),
    '%kh%im%ss'));
```

Comment: thx for your very nice reply @dylan-su :) how ever I most do something wrong when I use this, done manually as you demonstrate it run like a charm but when I try to  `set @from = '`length`';` it turns `28m54s` into `28` :(  what do i do wrong?

Comment: Hi @Dylan yes, should I change it into?   I can change it to whatever it should be, the db is only for manipulating data before importing to production DB

Comment: "the db is only for manipulating data before importing to production DB" - SQL really isn't suited for this.

Comment: Hm don't have a select :) as I was to use SqlYog to manipulate this and tried different things... but do add the string to question

Comment: Hi Dylan, thx but it returns a error 1064   posted it to original Q

Comment: Hi Dylan Su thx for your answer :) i did the trick :) I'm very happy

Answer (score 0):

Assuming length isn't really an integer...

```
SELECT CASE WHEN length LIKE '%h%' 
            THEN TIME_TO_SEC(STR_TO_DATE(length ,'%hh%im%ss')) 
            WHEN length LIKE '%m%' 
            THEN TIME_TO_SEC(STR_TO_DATE(length ,'%im%ss')) 
            ELSE TIME_TO_SEC(STR_TO_DATE(length ,'%ss')) 
        END x
  FROM my_table;
```

Comment: thanks @Strawberry but again using SET @val = '`length`'; turns 28m54s into 28..... I might not fully understand the select/update/set of this

Comment: hi Strawberry there are non, what I have is a csv import from foreign source in which I need to have the Value length changed from ex. 28m54s and into 1734 to be able to import it into my own database through web frontend... and yes I'm not used to do more "advanced" stuff than the use of UPDATE (coloumn, 'val1', 'val2')

Comment: thx Strawberry but it returns Error Code: 1054
Unknown column 'length' in 'field list'    have updated original Q

Comment: hmm missing.....  I do love challenges, and even when Dylan Su answer have fixed my job I'm not giving up on this one :)  have for now tried replacing ` with ' and " adding `db`.`table`  could I have first clue to his?

Comment: I hate thit phrase... I give up :(